# How to disable live tile support in My application

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I look at my app in the store via the phone I see  "with Live Tile" below Application title. But i didn't  swich on Live tile support in the application. Does anybody know how to disable this ability?

Answer (score 1):

The "with Live Tile" indicator is the store is auto detected.
You could see it if you have any of the following:

- a wide tile
- Push notifications
- Pinning/deep links (i.e. using `ShellTile.Create`)
- any use of `ShellTile.ActiveTiles`

Comment: hmm this is strange but  i do not use any of this! where i could find more information?

Comment: Have you included any 3rd party libraries which may include any of the above?